React Vite Route Guard redirection error when deploying on Netlify
I have a routing and redirection issue in my React Vite SPA when I deploy it on Netlify.
I have my routes as follows:
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<RouteGuard mode='private' />}>
      <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
      <Route index path='dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
      <Route path='categories' element={<CategoriesList />} />
      <Route path='recipes' element={<RecipesList />} />
      <Route path='addRecipe' element={<AddRecipeItem />} />
      <Route path='editRecipe/:id' element={<EditRecipeItem />} />
      <Route path='recipeItem/:id' element={<RecipeItem />} />
      <Route path='users' element={<UsersList />} />
      <Route path='userFavourites' element={<UserFavourites />} />
    </Route>

    <Route path='/' element={<RouteGuard mode='public' />}>
      <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
      <Route path='register' element={<Register />} />
      <Route path='verifyPass' element={<VerifyPass />} />
      <Route path='forgotPass' element={<ForgotPass />} />
      <Route path='resetPass' element={<ResetPass />} />
    </Route>

    <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>

And here is my RouteGuard component:
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AuthContext } from '../../contexts/global/authContext'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import { LoadingScreen } from '.'
import { useContext } from 'react'

const RouteGuard = ({ mode }) => {
  const { isLoading } = useContext(AuthContext)
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

  if (isLoading)
    return (
      <>
        <div className='vw-100 vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center gap-4 flex-column'>
          <LoadingScreen />
        </div>
      </>
    )

  if (mode === 'public') {
    return token ? <Navigate to='/' /> : <Outlet />
  } else {
    return token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/login' />
  }
}

export default RouteGuard

RouteGuard.propTypes = {
  mode: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}


Regarding the route guard, simply what I want to achieve is to prevent access to the private routes if the user is not authenticated, and prevent access to those public [auth] routes if the user is already signed in.
And in my netlify.toml config file, as per Netlify Docs, I have the following :
[[redirects]]
from = "/*"
to = "/index.html"
status = 200

and I also have the `redirects file in public folder.
So, simply, while development, everything works fine, but when I deploy to Netlify, I always get the NotFound component rendered, which is specified as error element in this route :
<Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />

I tried to debug this thing and test the routing without it to see what Netlify is doing actually, and all I got is a blank page for each route I have after I removed this route. So, I knew that the problem is in my RouteGuard, so, I removed the RouteGuard for testing and it worked. So, now I am sure that the problem is regarding the RouteGuard.
So, please can anyone help how to overcome this issue?
